# How to use apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf instead of 000-default.conf?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

nginx is configured as a reverse proxy for apache (2.4.18) and node with multiple domains.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`:

```bash
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  # /api is running on php/apache 
  location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  # all the rest is handled by node.js 
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com`:

```bash
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/api
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```bash
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        # ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added a symlink from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com` pointing to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com`.

Everything is fine except `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` doesn't work.
It still uses `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two VirtualHosts with same name `<VirtualHost *:8080>`. File `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` first file that read by Apache, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` is second, so Apache load only first file and it cover all other VirtulHosts files. To prevent such problems, you should remove `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or change content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` to

```
 <VirtualHost example.com:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/api
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache is well configured to listen only on port 8080. I don't see the standard apache page, but the page configured in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: @francoisromain please share contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: I completed the question above

Comment: @francoisromain please check updated answer.